# Finding all possible permutations of a fixed length of numbers to reach a given sum

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I'd like to modify the `subset_sum()` python function from [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum) so that:

1. It allows repeats (permutations) instead of combinations
2. It only considers permutations of a given length

I've successfully accomplished #2, but I need assistance with #1:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, length, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target and len(partial) == length:
        print(f"sum({partial})={target}")
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, length, partial + [n])
```

The desired output should be:

```
>>> subset_sum([3,9,8,4,5,7,10],target=15,length=3)
sum([3, 8, 4])=15
sum([3, 4, 8])=15
sum([4, 3, 8])=15
sum([4, 8, 3])=15
sum([8, 3, 4])=15
sum([8, 4, 3])=15
sum([3, 5, 7])=15
sum([3, 7, 5])=15
sum([5, 3, 7])=15
sum([5, 7, 3])=15
sum([7, 3, 5])=15
sum([7, 5, 3])=15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
import itertools

numbers = [3,9,8,4,5,7,10]
length = 3
target = 15

iterable = itertools.permutations(numbers,length)
predicate = lambda x: (sum(x) == target)
vals = filter(predicate,iterable)
list(vals)
```

Or a one-liner:

```
vals = [x for x in itertools.permutations(numbers,length) if sum(x) == target]
```

Results:

```
[(3, 8, 4),
 (3, 4, 8),
 (3, 5, 7),
 (3, 7, 5),
 (8, 3, 4),
 (8, 4, 3),
 (4, 3, 8),
 (4, 8, 3),
 (5, 3, 7),
 (5, 7, 3),
 (7, 3, 5),
 (7, 5, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've solved the problem of identifying *one* solution in each equivalence group, my advice is: do *not* alter that algorithm.  Instead, harness `itertools.permutations` to generate those items:

```
return list(itertools.permutations(numbers))
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. Can you elaborate on how to return the list of numbers from this recursive function rather than just printing them to the screen?

Comment: The `list` expression above gets inserted before the final return from the function.  You can check `partial` to see whether this is the top-level invocation.